# Variable fg_bold seems not to be defined in a zsh script, how come? (oh-my-sh)

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have been using oh-my-sh for the past few months,
and gosh I love it :), I have noticed there is an array of colors fg_bold[],
and by using the array we can echo informative message with colors.

for example:
echo $fg_bold[yellow] "Let's make it work!"

Executing this from terminal worked liked a charm.

BUT it seems if I open a brand new zsh script, and copy & paste it, it fails ($fg_bold[yellow] is empty):

> #!/usr/bin/zsh                 #taken from `which zsh`
>
> echo $fg_bold[yellow] "Let's make it work!"

More to add the fg_bold's array doesn't appear both in `env` and in `printenv`.
What am i missing here?

Thank you all

Answer (score 5):

That variable is pulled from the  `colors` autoloadable function.

You need to load and run that function:

```
autoload colors
colors
```

Note that you can also use prompt expansion which doesn't need that `colors` function:

```
print -P %F{red}
```

Or:

```
echo ${(%):-%F{red}}
```

In any case, that's an associative array *shell* variable, not something that can or should be exported to the environment. If you want to see its declaration, use `typeset -p fg_bold` (note that the variable has the `-H` (hide value) attribute, so `typeset -p` would show the values, you can remove that attribute with `typeset +H fg_bold`, or see the values with `typeset fg_bold`).

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer well appreciated,
I just now read the man zshmisc.